# What kind of alien homeworld would result in the following kind of alien (i.e. my Enslavers) naturally evolving?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, military

Pictures are provided below. But overall there are three sentient alien species, at the top of the universe food chain in my setting. One of them are the Enslaver Aliens (different individuals shown below) who naturally evolved on a planet that emphasize such characteristics and resulted in one of the three most deadly species in the universe.

Enslavers are able to grow to the height of a fifteen storey building, capable of floating in mid air, mind control thousands to hundreds of thousands of human beings, teleport occasionally, control the local weather, create forcefields and have a strong control of telekinesis. They are sentient creatures with [blue and orange alien morality](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlueAndOrangeMorality) which makes sense. And they were able to create their own starships to colonize their galaxy.

Each Enslaver is a deadly natural disaster to human civilization and a threat to the human species similar to the Yellowstone Eruption. Fortunately, over the course of 20 years, in my modern setting, only four of them actually appear. They are immortal beings that only grow stronger with age but their growth slows down overtime. They are confident in themselves, though rightly so. Humanity has right to fear such creatures. They see as as cattle at best, ants at worst.

Killing a full grown Enslaver literally requires, in my story setting either requires:

1. Multiple Hiroshima Level Nuclear Warheads
2. Being willing to sacrifice ten of thousands of soldiers in weeks long battles
3. Sacrifice hundreds of Super Soldiers over the course of days
4. Willing to wipe out an entire city to even a small country to steal its "prey"

As these aren't really hard science fiction tropes I happy to consider them being created in a Lovecraft Environment. They are Alien Eldritch Abominations after all. But the reasoning for how they naturally evolved has to make sense.

The question is thus quite simple. What kind of environment or homeworld would see to the natural evolution of such a creature?

[image: Enslaver 1]
[image: ENSLAVER W]
[image: Enslaver 3]
[image: enslaver 4]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138628/discussion-on-question-by-colonizerofthesun-what-kind-of-alien-homworld-would-re).

Comment: For a good example, maybe checking out what's known about the origin planet of another Lovecraftian alien race, the [mi-go](https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Mi-go) and their colony planet [yuggoth](https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Yuggoth) might help you get a better grasp on how to better describe it. It's ok for you to know all the details (I myself am not a fan of having things left unanswered or handwaving more than needed), but for this specific kind of story, sometimes it's better when you actually can't know it all.

Comment: They creatures definitely have some similarities with the [affronters](https://theculture.fandom.com/wiki/Affront) in the culture series, which evolved floating in a high-pressure gas environment.

Comment: On Earth, air is not very dense compared a 15-story creature.  There's a physics problem here.  Floating things tend to be quite tiny. Have you seen a [Ballooning Spider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrS0igctMi0)?

Comment: I think to plausibly explain what sort of world would have led to the natural evolution of *telekinesis* and *mind control*, you need to have some idea of how those things actually work. In particular for natural evolution of traits to make sense *every step along the way* to developing those traits has to provide competitive advantage (in the environment that existed at the time, which also changes over time). Doesn't have to be **real** science, but some sort of internally consistent fictional science that allows you to break these abilities down a bit more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The look to me like some kind of floater, that's evolved in a gas giant world.

Space faring creatures that have evolved from gas giants have always been a mystery, since they have no way of evolving tech like smelting metals or controlled fire for that matter. Though intelligence is possible. Any technological advancement beyond simple tools if physically impossible (Improbable?), without outside assistance.

I see this species starting out in a floater environment, perhaps a hot jupiter, or rather a "warm" jupiter. plenty of energy from the host star, a brown dwarf,  for life to evolve in the improbable environment of the gas giant.

Our creature is a parasite. finding its home within the relatively tiny brain of the host floater. There it lives it's entire life cycle within the host.

The Host is a predatory floater. using its squid like locomotion of squeezing out atmosphere to propel itself forward. Where it uses bioelectric shocks to overwhelm it's prey.

Over time the creatures evolved, in the unchanging environment millions and millions of years pass. Eventually the parasite and host are inseparable, indistinguishable, integrated into a single being. And by chance intelligence evolved. Though with two minds. One the old host still primitive, the other the Parasite, dominant and controlling. They are territorial, and war among themselves for mates and the best gas belts which are fertile with prey. Millions more years pass Bioelectric has evolved into Telekinetic, and telepathic. Their conflict has sharpened their skills.

One day they look up and see something beyond the cloud tops. Something not a cloud or a floater, something alien. They reach out with their minds to the aliens minds and find them simple, and tiny, easily overwhelmed, as if they have never touched another mind before. Yet full of information, knowledge they can grasp but out of their reach for all of their existence.  They reach out and bind the alien minds. As they bind their hosts. They force them to take them up into the ships. Their hosts rebel, terrified of the closed in spaces within the tiny vessels. But they will obey they have always obeyed.

TLDR: parasite on bioelectric host, that lives on gas giant. Parasite evolves with host over extraordinarily long period of time telekinetic powers. But cant evolve technologically because the environment prevents basic mechanical means of production. Eventually are discovered by alien race which are themselves over taken and mind enslaved and used and a means of escape from their gaseous environment.

Answer (score 17):

**Microcosm**

Your Enslaver looks like something more suited to being tiny and a liquid environment. Like these zooplankton.

[image]

[image]

This is exactly where it came from. The Enslaver lives in a liquid envionment, similar to the Lovecraftian [Far Realm](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Realm) from D&D where "The Air is Viscuous as Syrup".

In their universe the enslavers are tiny creatures that band together using a telepathic field to communicate with the rest of the swarm.

Number 1 rule of Dimensional Hopping: Portal size matters. There is no notion of relative size between dimensions. How big the enslaver is when it comes out on our side depends on the size of the tho portals. If our portal is twice as big it comes out twice as big.

Number 2 rule of Dimensional Hopping: Creatures obey their own rules. Normally a creature the size of a skyscraper would collapse under its own weight. But Rule 2 means it doesn't. it also explains why it is so hard to kill, since small things are generally harder to kill. Sometimes I swat flies and they go paff to the other side of the room and keep buzzing about. And your enslaver is smaller than a fly.

Comment: This answer is genius. Instead of conjuring a pseudo-scientific explanation, this answer embraces the madness of the creature, and takes it all the way to its logical conclusion.

Comment: This perfectly works together with @Gillgamesh's answer: In a gas giant, the "liquidity" is a different thing, and therefore "tiny" can be  entirely different as well

Answer (score 3):

Evolution seems unlikely. Predators don't evolve more than they need to to get their prey.

But engineered biological weapons make sense. Get a huge creature and modify it into a weapon if you have the tech seems something we'd do on Earth if given half a chance.

If such a thing could get loose, wipe the floor with us and then go rampaging around then there's your creature.

Comment: The first sentence is trivially proven wrong by the existence of humans. The way hunter-gatherers hunted (mainly persistence hunting), could have been done with less intelligence than we have. We needed the intelligence we have for very complex social dynamics. Hunting in groups does require some intelligence, but many animal species manage it just fine. Even using sharpened sticks and stones can be done with less intelligence than we have.

Comment: @vsz thats true enough, we didn't evolve as predators though, our intelligence is an evolution probably in order to better function in societies. How many of us actually hunt these days? Yet we still need the intelligence

Comment: @Kilisi The key point is that predators (like all creatures) evolve not just in competition with their prey, but in competition with other members of their own species. Even if one phenotype of a predator species is "evolved enough" to catch their prey, if there is not an infinite availability of prey then another phenotype that is *better* at catching the poor prey will still out-compete the original phenotype, and so the overall species continues to evolve. That's not even getting into things like sexual selection that can drive rapid evolutionary change without *any* outside pressure.

Answer (score 1):

## High Energy World

These creatures, unlike puny humans living about a weak star, live in a realm of unknown physics. Their homeworld is dominated by energy gradients that would destroy lesser lifeforms. However, the enslaver's sort of life harnessed this power

While the enslaver's power would be overkill to ensnare terrestrial prey, it would be quite proportionate for taking down mobile phytoids, or running away from  an even more powerful predator